# Java newFixedThreadPool explanation

Tags: java, multithreading, wso2

I am trying to diagnose a problem I am having using WSO2 identity management.

```
package org.wso2.carbon.identity.mgt;

import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

/**
 * email sender this creates a new task in thread pool for each email sending request
 */
public class NotificationSender {

    private static ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    NotificationSendingModule module;

    /**
     * creates and submits a task to the thread pool
     *
     * @param module email sending module as task
     */
    public void sendNotification(NotificationSendingModule module) {

        threadPool.submit(module);
    }

    public NotificationSendingModule getModule() {
        return module;
    }
}
```

I am load testing the user creation process, and at the point where WSO2 sends a User credentials configuration mail it is sending multiple to the same email address even though they are unique.

I have never used Java but am familiar with C#, so have been able to read through the code without issue, and my questions is:

In the Java docs it mentions "If a thread terminates due to failure during execution and prior to shutdown, a new thread is created to take its place."

Does this mean that if the email send encounters an error then a new thread will begin the process again?

I'm thinking perhaps the send email is erroring so a new thread is created, but the logging with isn't tied into a result is performed anyway.

Also, is it ok to never call

```
threadPool.shutdown()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a thread that is part of a thread pool throws an exception it is indeed replaced with a new fresh thread.  However it will not retry the same operation.  The replacement only occurs so the thread pool can continue do its work when more tasks needs to be executed.

Normally when a thread is terminated in such a fashion, a stack trace is logged, but it is possible the exception is swallowed somewhere.  You could try adding a try-catch block around the sending code and logging any exception explicitly to analyze the problem further.

Not calling `shutdown` is fine.

Comment: Thanks John, that narrows it down a  bit more

Answer (score 1):

> I am load testing the user creation process, and at the point where WSO2 sends a User credentials configuration mail it is sending multiple to the same email address even though they are unique.

Well, when I hear a Java framework/app server doing identity management + thread pools + strange behavior, what immediatly comes to mind is that most frameworks use a thread per user model (that is : the user identity is tied to the thread. if you switch threads, the user authentication data is lost). Now I do not know if that is the case with SO2, but refer to the documentation. It is the "usual suspect" : thread local authentication mechanisms are everywhere.

> In the Java docs it mentions "If a thread terminates due to failure during execution and prior to shutdown, a new thread is created to take its place."
>   Does this mean that if the email send encounters an error then a new thread will begin the process again?

No. It means that a new thread will be created to handle other unit of works as they are / have been submitted. But the failed unit of work will not be attempted again. As far as the thread pool is concerned, the task completed (with an exception), and it is done with it.

> Also, is it ok to never call `threadPool.shutdown()`

It is not. You should either make your `NotificationSender` class have a `close()` or `end()` method of some sort. Or maybe tie it with some of WSO2 lifecycle callbacks (e.g. in a servlet context, you have listeners for lifecycle events, in a Spring container, you have other create/destroy callbacks, ... whatever works in your context). Failure to shut down a thread pool implies that some threads will hang around, and their resources never freed. Threads are coming pretty cheap nowadays, but they may still pile up and bit you in the long run. It may only be *kind of* ok if you are sure you only create one `NotificationSender` in your whole app, and that the lifecycle of this object is the same as your app. Then, essentially, shutting it down is the same as shutting the app down and so nothing bad really happens.